# How to do the coin effect in Eatventure

Tags: unity, animation, dotween

[image: Eatventure Coin Effect]

I'm trying to do the flying coin effect in the video using DOTween in Unity. I already made an object pooling system to generate large amount of coin but I'm currently stuck on how to make the animation itself. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement to use DOTween? Or would you be open to solutions that do not use this?

Comment: Any solution is fine!